# App engine push task always returns 404 in test

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-app-engine-go

I've got a push task queue in a Go App Engine application. When we try to enqueue tasks in testing for whatever reason the tasks always return 404.

Our app.yaml:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1.9

handlers:
 - url: /worker/.*
   script: _go_app
   login: admin
 - url: /.*
   script: _go_app
```

The actual task invocation:

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    t := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask("/worker", map[string][]string{"key": {"val"}})
    _, err := taskqueue.Add(ctx, t, "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Failed to add task");
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Success");
}
```

A still-incomplete handler, but it exists!

```
func Worker(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    log.Infof(ctx, "Worker succeeded")
}
```

and finally, proof that we actually added the path to our router:

```
func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/worker", Worker)
}
```

When we actually run tests, we always get the following logging output:

```
INFO     2018-05-03 09:51:11,794 module.py:846] default: "POST /worker HTTP/1.1" 404 19
WARNING  2018-05-03 09:51:11,794 taskqueue_stub.py:2149] Task � failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.100 seconds
INFO     2018-05-03 09:51:11,897 module.py:846] default: "POST /worker HTTP/1.1" 404 19
WARNING  2018-05-03 09:51:11,897 taskqueue_stub.py:2149] Task � failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.200 seconds
INFO     2018-05-03 09:51:12,101 module.py:846] default: "POST /worker HTTP/1.1" 404 19
WARNING  2018-05-03 09:51:12,101 taskqueue_stub.py:2149] Task � failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.400 seconds
```

Note that the `/worker` endpoint returns 302 when I try to ping it via an API client like Paw, so the route seems to have been configured correctly. The 404 only arises when I try to run things in a test.

Why is this returning 404? I've tried running tests around the example push queue in their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/taskqueue/push/example) have run into the same issue there - is there some sort of missing configuration flag I'm failing to pass to `goapp`?

I've pushed up a GitHub repo with a minimal replicable example [here](https://github.com/venantius/google-app-engine-taskqueue-404-example)

Comment: Did you register your `mux`? How? Please show that code.

Comment: Also `api_version` must be `go1`, this is not the Go's version.

Comment: `go1.9` is a supported `api_version`, but it's currently on beta support. Refer to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#api_version

Comment: Added code showing where `mux` is registered.

Comment: Do your other handlers work? If you don't have other handlers, please add one for testing purposes.

Comment: All of my normal HTTP handlers work fine - I've got an SPA frontend that proxies to them and haven't had any issues so far. I didn't include the code for them because I haven't had any issues with them and didn't want to introduce any confusion. They're added to the same mux the same way.

Comment: Also added an extra note - just tried out the endpoint via Paw and got a 302, indicating at the very least that the `app.yaml` configuration is correct.

Comment: What is the Return URL for the 302 response?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/worker/settle`

Comment: And is that a 404 locally? If so that may be your problem

Comment: @TarunLalwani sorry, that URL happens to be incorrect because I was tweaking the routes, but yes - regardless of what's specified, it's correct, because that URL is auto-generated by App Engine when you set `login: admin` in `app.yaml` on a particular route.

Answer (score 4):

The order for running goapp is top-bottom but you need to be specific in your app.yaml. In your case this will works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue"
)

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    t := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask("/worker", map[string][]string{"key": {"val"}})
    _, err := taskqueue.Add(ctx, t, "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Failed to add task")
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Success")
}

func Worker(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    log.Infof(ctx, "Worker succeeded")
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/worker", Worker)
}
```

For this you need to map url like:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1.9

handlers:
 - url: /worker
   script: _go_app
   login: admin
 - url: /.*
   script: _go_app
```

The result is:

[image]

See that worker is running two times. This is ocurring because `GET /favicon.ico` is entering in `GET /.*` mapping. So this is only details for you!

**UPDATE (05/14/2018):**
In your test you use `aetest.NewInstance()`, that runs dev_appserver.py in `ioutil.TempDir("", "appengine-aetest")`, that writes your own main.go and app.yaml. See above in `instance_vm.go`:

```
i.appDir, err = ioutil.TempDir("", "appengine-aetest")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer func() {
    if err != nil {
        os.RemoveAll(i.appDir)
    }
}()
err = os.Mkdir(filepath.Join(i.appDir, "app"), 0755)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
err = ioutil.WriteFile(filepath.Join(i.appDir, "app", "app.yaml"), []byte(i.appYAML()), 0644)
  if err != nil {
    return err
}
err = ioutil.WriteFile(filepath.Join(i.appDir, "app", "stubapp.go"), []byte(appSource), 0644)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

//... others codes

const appYAMLTemplate = `
application: %s
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1
vm: true
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
`

const appSource = `
package main
import "google.golang.org/appengine"
func main() { appengine.Main() }
`
```

So you need to create your own server-instance. This is a way:

```
//out buffer
var out bytes.Buffer
//start server
c := exec.Command("goapp", "serve") //default port=8080, adminPort=8000
c.Stdout = &out
c.Stderr = &out
c.Start()
defer c.Process.Kill()
//delay to wait server is completed
time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

//... others codes

//quit server
quitReq, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8000/quit", nil)
_, err := client.Do(quitReq)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Errorf("GET /quit handler error: %v", err)
}
```

To test your Handler function do:

```
//create request (testing Handler func)
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8080/", nil)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err.Error())
}
//do GET
client := http.DefaultClient
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
//delay to wait for the worker to execute
time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
```

To retrieve the result and test it:

```
//read response
b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
resp_content := string(b)
//checking
if !strings.Contains(resp_content, "Handler Success") {
    t.Errorf("Handler not working")
}
//log server content
logserver := out.String()
if !strings.Contains(logserver, "Worker succeeded") {
    t.Errorf("Worker not working")
}
//log response
t.Logf(logserver)
```

The result is:

[image: screenshot - test result]

**UPDATE: Link for Github: https://github.com/ag-studies/go-appengine-sample**

Hope this help!!

Comment: Can you provide a GitHub repository with a working example? The code you've provided still has the same error on my machine, though we could have written our test differently.

Comment: Updated with link for github.

Comment: That repo doesn't seem to have a test file. This question is specifically about running tests. Were your logs from tests or just from running a dev server?

Answer (score 3):

Your `handlers` pattern is `/worker/.*` but you are issuing tasks to `/worker`.

You should do 1 of the following:

1. Either change pattern to `/worker.*` or just `/worker`
2. Or issue request(s) to `/worker/` or `/worker/some-task-name`.

Comment: Did you register your task handler? Can you provide code for this?

Comment: All of the code for registering handlers is included both in the question and in the linked GitHub repo.

Comment: Should work when running with `goapp serve`. What do you mean by "running tests"? Are your refereing to `aetest`? If so I think there is known issue with supporting task queues there. But `goapp serve` should work after fixing pattern.

Comment: Yes, this works fine with `goapp serve`. I do mean using `aetest` // `goapp test`.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to known issues on supporting task queues on Google (other than supporting custom task queues, which is different from this issue).

Comment: I’ve seen your issue https://github.com/golang/appengine/issues/134 and did not realize it was yours. Never tested queues with aetes but I recall for Python we had to implement custom hack and call in test something like custom process_queues. So I guess it can be similar with Go.